# Problem regarding components of forces in conical pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

For the motion of conical pendulum we can write equations as

$$T_{F}\cos\theta =mg$$

$$T_{F}\sin\theta=\frac{mv^2}{R}$$

$T_{F}$ represents tension in the string.

$v$ is the velocity of bob at this instant.

$R$ is the radius of circle.

But if we split $mg$ into its components,we can write

$$T_{F}=mg\cos\theta$$(because length of the string is constant)

What does then $mg \sin\theta$ will do? Also $mg \sin\theta$ is  not in plane of circle. So what causes centripetal acceleration if I split components like this?

Comment: Your first and last equations contradict each other. The last one is wrong as $T_F$  and the component of $mg$ in the direction of the string do not balance, because $T_F$ (or a component of it) provides the bob's centripetal acceleration.

Comment: If $T_{F} \neq mgcos\theta$ then length of the string should not remain constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
you have three forces that must be in equilibrium, these is independent of the coordinate system that you chosen

**x-y system**

$$\sum F_x={\frac {m{v}^{2}}{R}}-T_{{F}}\sin \left( \theta \right)= 0$$
$$\sum F_y=-mg+T_{{F}}\cos \left( \theta \right)=0 $$

**x'-y' system**

$$\sum F_x'={\frac {m{v}^{2}\cos \left( \theta \right) }{R}}-\sin \left( \theta
 \right) mg
=0$$
$$\sum F_y'=-{\frac {\sin \left( \theta \right) m{v}^{2}}{R}}-\cos \left( \theta
 \right) mg+T_{{F}}
=0$$

in both coordinate system you obtain the same solutions

$$T_F=\frac{m\,g}{\cos(\theta)}$$
$$v=\sqrt{g\,r\,\tan(\theta)}$$

thus the choice of the coordinate system can't affected the results.

I am not sure that this answer your question?

Comment: Also $v$ should be $\sqrt{gr\tan\theta}$

Answer (score 2):

> I'm asking for reason why you can split Tension(first case) but not mg(second case)

When you say 'splitting,' you really mean projecting a force along some axis.

First let's cover why you 'split' the tension as you did in your first approach.

You know that the net force in the y-direction is zero; finding the y-component of tension helps you solve the problem. That's why you bother to 'split.'

> Q. Why can't I split the force of gravity?

A. Of course you can! The question, is, however, **along what axes**?

From what I understood, you decided to calculate the component of gravity force that lies on the same axis as the tension force (or the string). There is nothing wrong with that. **However**, the true equation you'd get would be:

$$0 = T - mg\cos\theta + F_{\rm fictitious}$$

The reference frame you chose is **non inertial**. Though there is no motion along the string, the string itself is accelerating. Thus, there will be what we can call a [fictitious force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force).

The whole reason why we 'split' along x- and y-axis in this problem is because the frame is inertial, so we can solve for the tension.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can write $T_F = mgcos \theta$, since in the first line, you've clearly (and correctly) have written $T_F cos \theta = mg$. To be more intuitive, imagine a vector in direction of $T_F$, which is a component of $mg$. For the rope's length to remain constant, this vector's magnitude should be equal to $T_F$, only in the opposite direction of $T_F$. From the image of the question, you can see that this vector's length is clearly longer than $mg$, so this must be equal to $mg/ cos \theta$ and not $mg cos \theta$.

Comment: I'm asking for reason why you can split Tension(first case) but not $mg$(second case)

Comment: @user1000 I've edited my answer.